# How bind my predictions trained on a subset, back to the original DF?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am making predictions on a feature engineered training set, without any identification key. How can I merge my predictions back to the original df?

Original_DF

```
ID.  ColumnB.   ColumnC.   ColumnD.  Target 
   A        2          3        1          8
   B        2          3        1          9
   C        2          3        1          6
```

Then I trained my model on ColumnC and ColumnD, resulting in:

```
Subset_to_use = ['ColumnC', 'ColumnD', 'Target']
....
#Creating Train / Test resulting in train and test set, and X and Y:  
X_train, y_train
X_test,   y_test 

# Then doing the modelling, simplified: 
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100) 
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then the question: **how can I bind the predictions back to the original_df? Since there is no ID column in anymore?**

Training df:

```
ColumnC.   ColumnD.  Target 
   3        1          8
   3        1          9
   3        1          6
```

My thinking directions:

```
# Add the predictions to the df 
X_train['Prediction_TEST'] = y_train. # to have the original values 
X_test['Prediction_TEST'] = rf.predict(X_test) # to have the predicted values
```

and then to combine the above, like:

```
all_data = pd.concat(X_train, X_test])
```

However, this is only giving the Training and testing DF with the new predictions, but WITHOUT the other original columns (e.g., ColumnA and ColumnB).

What is the best way to solve this? Thank you!

Desired outcome (predicted values are made up):

```
ID.  ColumnB.   ColumnC.   ColumnD.  Target     Predicted
   A        2          3        1          8       8
   B        2          3        1          9       10
   C        2          3        1          6       7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index should not matter so long as the size of the output matches the size of the input:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# Reproducible data
csv_data = StringIO("""ID,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,Target
A,2,3,1,8
B,2,3,1,9
C,2,3,1,6""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_data, index_col=0)

reg = RandomForestRegressor()
reg.fit(df[["ColumnB", "ColumnC", "ColumnD"]], df["Target"])

# Create a `Predicted` column representing testing on the train set
df["Predicted"] = reg.predict(df[["ColumnB", "ColumnC", "ColumnD"]])

print(df)
```

The `Predicted` column now contains the result of applying the trained random forest regressor. The `ID` values should not matter here.

```
    ColumnB  ColumnC  ColumnD  Target  Predicted
ID                                              
A         2        3        1       8       7.74
B         2        3        1       9       7.74
C         2        3        1       6       7.74
```

---

Now consider the case where you have separate `train` and `test` splits, and each should only have access to `ColumnC` and `ColumnD`:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Reproducible data
csv_data = StringIO("""ID,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,Target
A,2,3,1,8
B,2,3,1,9
C,2,3,1,6""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_data, index_col=0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df[["ColumnC", "ColumnD"]], df["Target"], random_state=42,
)

reg = RandomForestRegressor()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

`X_train` and `X_test` are still `DataFrame` objects, so we can add columns representing the regressor's predictions:

```py
X_train["train_predictions"] = reg.predict(X_train)
X_test["test_predictions"] = reg.predict(X_test)
```

`X_test` now looks like this, and `X_train` should look similar:

```
    ColumnC  ColumnD  test_predictions
ID                                    
A         3        1             7.545
```

The indexes should have been preserved through each step of our transformation, so we can drop the duplicate columns `C` and `D` and `join` back on the original `df`:

```py
df = df.join([
    X_train.drop(["ColumnC", "ColumnD"], axis=1),
    X_test.drop(["ColumnC", "ColumnD"], axis=1),
])
```

Giving us:

```
    ColumnB  ColumnC  ColumnD  Target  train_predictions  test_predictions
ID                                                                        
A         2        3        1       8                NaN             7.695
B         2        3        1       9              7.695               NaN
C         2        3        1       6              7.695               NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. But how does this works with a Train and Test set as the examplke? Because above, you trained it on a full df. Thank you in advance, appreciated.

Comment: If you have two data frames (train and test), you can concatenate them together, assuming they both have a "Predicted" column like the one shown here. However: the interpretation of those values would be different, so you would *probably* want another column representing whether the row was in the train or test set.

Comment: I re-read the original question and I think I understand it better now. I've updated this answer with an addendum that better addresses train/test splits.